# How to replace missing rows with the latest value from previous days in SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

This is my first question here, to all Athena SQL experts out there

I have a athena database with a table that contains user data for the last 2 years. 
This table is store in S3 in parquet format, partitioned by date (a column called dt).

Each row of the table contains the user Id, a timestamp, a few properties (prop1, prop2, prop3) and the partition key dt.

Every day (dt) I have zero, one or more entries per user.
I need to write a Athena SQL query, that outputs all the data for the last 2 years, having for every day (dt) the latest user information. 
This means, I need to propagate across time the lastest user information if it isn't present in a particular dt.

**Example Input table:**

```
|    dt    |UserId|     timestamp          |p1 |p2 |p3 |
|----------|------|------------------------|---|---|---|
|01/09/2019|    A |2019-09-01T09:50:04.082Z|x  |y  |z  |
|01/09/2019|    A |2019-09-01T10:52:04.082Z|r  |t  |g  |
|01/09/2019|    B |2019-09-01T11:02:04.082Z|a  |s  |d  |
|01/09/2019|    C |2019-09-01T10:10:04.082Z|z  |x  |c  |
|----------|------|------------------------|---|---|---|
|02/09/2019|    B |2019-09-02T11:02:04.082Z|a  |s  |d  |
|----------|------|------------------------|---|---|---|
|03/09/2019|    A |2019-09-03T12:50:04.082Z|fd |swq|qw |
|03/09/2019|    B |2019-09-03T11:02:04.082Z|wre|ewr|we |
|----------|------|------------------------|---|---|---|
|04/09/2019|    J |2019-09-04T11:02:04.082Z|dc |qw |w3 |
|----------|------|------------------------|---|---|---|
|05/09/2019|    A |2019-09-05T11:02:04.082Z|qdw|qw |rg |
|05/09/2019|    B |2019-09-05T11:02:04.082Z|g  |de |ew |
|05/09/2019|    J |2019-09-05T11:02:04.082Z|egr|gre|rg |
```

**Example Output table:**

```
|   dt     |UserId|     timestamp          |p1 |p2 |p3 |
|----------|------|------------------------|---|---|---|
|01/09/2019|   A  |2019-09-01T10:52:04.082Z|r  | t | g |
|01/09/2019|   B  |2019-09-01T11:02:04.082Z|a  | s | d |
|01/09/2019|   C  |2019-09-01T10:10:04.082Z|z  | x | c |
|----------|------|------------------------|---|---|---|
|02/09/2019|   B  |2019-09-02T11:02:04.082Z|a  | s | d |
|02/09/2019|   A  |2019-09-01T10:52:04.082Z|r  | t | g |
|02/09/2019|   C  |2019-09-01T10:10:04.082Z|z  | x | c |
|----------|------|------------------------|---|---|---|
|03/09/2019|   A  |2019-09-03T12:50:04.082Z|fd |swq|qw |
|03/09/2019|   B  |2019-09-03T11:02:04.082Z|wre|ewr|we |
|03/09/2019|   C  |2019-09-01T10:10:04.082Z|z  | x |c  |
|----------|------|------------------------|---|---|---|
|04/09/2019|   J  |2019-09-04T11:02:04.082Z|dc |qw |w3 |
|04/09/2019|   A  |2019-09-03T12:50:04.082Z|fd |swq|qw |
|04/09/2019|   B  |2019-09-03T11:02:04.082Z|wre|ewr|we |
|04/09/2019|   C  |2019-09-01T10:10:04.082Z|z  |x  |c  |
|----------|------|------------------------|---|---|---|
|05/09/2019|   A  |2019-09-05T11:02:04.082Z|qdw|qw |rg |
|05/09/2019|   B  |2019-09-05T11:02:04.082Z|g  |de |ew |
|05/09/2019|   J  |2019-09-05T11:02:04.082Z|egr|gre|rg |
|05/09/2019|   C  |2019-09-01T10:10:04.082Z|z  |x  |c  |
|----------|------|------------------------|---|---|---|
```

Edited:

To make it easier to try out approaches here is a query to create the above table and select all items from it:

```
WITH the_table AS (
  SELECT '01/09/2019' AS dt, 'A' AS user_id, '2019-09-01T09:50:04.082Z' AS timestamp, 'x' as p1, 'y' as p2, 'z' as p3
  UNION ALL SELECT '01/09/2019', 'A', '2019-09-01T10:52:04.082Z', 'r', 't', 'g'
  UNION ALL SELECT '01/09/2019', 'B', '2019-09-01T11:02:04.082Z', 'a', 's', 'd'
  UNION ALL SELECT '01/09/2019', 'C', '2019-09-01T10:10:04.082Z', 'z', 'x', 'c'
  UNION ALL SELECT '02/09/2019', 'B', '2019-09-02T11:02:04.082Z', 'a', 's', 'd'
  UNION ALL SELECT '03/09/2019', 'A', '2019-09-03T12:50:04.082Z', 'fd', 'swq', 'qw'
  UNION ALL SELECT '03/09/2019', 'B', '2019-09-03T11:02:04.082Z', 'wre', 'ewr', 'we'
  UNION ALL SELECT '04/09/2019', 'J', '2019-09-04T11:02:04.082Z', 'dc', 'qw', 'w3'
  UNION ALL SELECT '05/09/2019', 'A', '2019-09-05T11:02:04.082Z', 'qdw', 'qw', 'rg'
  UNION ALL SELECT '05/09/2019', 'B', '2019-09-05T11:02:04.082Z', 'g', 'de', 'ew'
  UNION ALL SELECT '05/09/2019', 'J', '2019-09-05T11:02:04.082Z', 'egr', 'gre', 'rg'
  ORDER BY dt ASC
)

SELECT * from the_table
```

Comment: What did you already try? Did you research something?

Comment: @Perazim I've tried windowing approach with LAG, but that didn't accomplish the final result.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key to this is the [`MAX_BY`](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/aggregate.html#max_by) aggregate function. What you do is you group by the date and user ID, and use `MAX_BY` on all the other columns, something like this:

```
SELECT
  dt,
  user_id,
  MAX_BY(p1, timestamp) AS p1,
  MAX_BY(p2, timestamp) AS p2,
  -- etc.
FROM the_table
GROUP BY dt, user_id
```

`MAX_BY` returns the value of the first column in the group where the second column has the highest value, i.e. the `p1` value for the highest `timestamp` value in the first case.

Comment: With this I would only exclude the oldest entry per user per day, but it wouldn't add an entry for the dt where there wasn't already one.

Comment: You're right, I must have misunderstood you or missed that requirement. One way to ensure that is to create the cross product of the distinct dates and user IDs and join that in to ensure there's a row for each combination – but there might be more efficient ways of doing it.